# runtime complexity of for loop with modulo

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity, modulo, number-theory

The question is to find a pair of integers (a,b) from a set M of unsigned integers, where a-b is a multiple of n. Given a positive integer n, which is less than the length (m) of set M.
Here is the snippet I have written.

I am not too sure about the time complexity of this algorithm w.r.t the length of M and the value of n. In the exlude function, worst case is O(m). Then it is within a for loop over m, then O(m^2). In addition, X initialization scales with n, so O(n) here. In total: O(m^2) + O(n), ignoring the other O(1)s. Is this correct?

Also, should I take `r = x % n` as O(1)?

Any coding related advices on the codes here are welcome!!! Big thx!

```
//array X is intialized of size n, all -1. Here the code is omitted.
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        if (currentLength > 1)
        {
            index = rand() % currentLength;
            x = setM[index];
            exclude(setM, index, &currentLength);
            r = x % n;
            if (X[r] == -1)
            {
                X[r] = x;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("The pair: (%i, %i)\n", X[r], x);
                break;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            break;
        }
        currentLength -= 1;
    }
```

```
// to exclude an element based on index, then shift all elements behind by 1 slot

void exclude(int* array, int index, int* length_ptr)
{
    if (index != *length_ptr - 1)
    {
        for (int i = index; i < *length_ptr - 1; i++)
        {
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `... nonnegative numbers ...` Use unsigned, and the modulo will be free of surprises.

Comment: By writing 'k' did you mean 'n'?

Comment: Yes! That was a typo. I just edited it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `%` performs a division, so that would be `O(1)`.

Comment: Marvin, Post some samples to better illustrate your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, should I take `r = x % n` as O(1)?

Yes, it's O(1)

> I am not too sure about the time complexity of this algorithm ... In total: O(m^2) + O(n)?

Well, kind of **but there is more to it than that**. The thing is that `m` and `n` is **not independent**.

Consider the case `n = 2` and let `m` be increasing. **Your formula would give O(m^2) but is that correct? No.** Since there will only be 2 possible results from `% n` (i.e. 0 and 1) the loop `for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)` can only run 3 times before we have a match. No matter how much you increase `m` there can never be more than 3 loops. In each of these loops the `exclude` function may move near `m` elements in worst case. In general the `for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)` can never do more than `n+1` loops.

So for `m being larger than n` you rather have O(n*m) + O(n). When keeping `n` constant this turns into just O(m). So your algorithm is just O(m) with respect to `m`.

Now consider the case with a constant `m` and a large increasing `n`. In this case your formula gives O(m^2) + O(n). Since `m` is constant O(m^2) is also constant so your algorithm is just O(n) with respect to `n`.

Now if you increase **both** `m` and `n` your formula gives O(m^2) + O(n). But since `m` and `n` are both increased, O(m^2) will eventually dominate O(N), so we can ignore O(N). In other words, your algorithm is O(M^2) with respect to both.

To recap:

```
O(m)   for constant n and increasing m
O(n)   for constant m and increasing n
O(m^2) for increasing n and increasing m
```

> Any coding related advices on the codes here are welcome

Well, this `index = rand() % currentLength;` is **just a bad idea!**

You should always test the last element in the array, i.e. `index = currentLength - 1;`

Why? Simply because that will turn `exclude` into O(1). In fact you won't even need it! The exclude will happen automatically when doing `currentLength -= 1;`

This change will improve complexicity like

```
O(1)      for constant n and increasing m
O(n)      for constant m and increasing n
O(m)+O(n) for increasing n and increasing m
```

The O(m)+O(n) can be said to be just O(m) (or just O(n)) as you prefer. The main thing is that it is linear.

Besides that you don't need `currentLength`. Change the main loop to be

```
for (int i = m-1; i >= 0; --i)
```

and use `i` as `index`. This simplifies your code to:

```
for (int i = m-1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    r = setM[i] % n;
    if (X[r] == -1)
    {
        X[r] = setM[i];
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The pair: (%i, %i)\n", X[r], setM[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: A massive thx! you made it crystal clear for me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find two numbers x and y that `x%n==y%n`.
It easy. Use a hash table with a key of `x %n`. Add consequtive numbers from the set until you find a duplicate. It would be the desired pair. Complexity is O(M).

Comment: That is a good idea! I will try it! But in this implementation, is it O(m^2) + O(n)? Just to check if understand how time complexity is estimated.

Comment: @Marwin Actually you almost have implemented hash table solution. Table X would be a perfect hash table assuming that 'n' is small (less than billions). Just remove 'exclude' from your code